# How to use jwt token with httpOnly when sending a request to api

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am making an app that allows logins, and when you login it sends a jwt to the cookies.

My app allows people to create tasks, but I cannot do so without the jwt token. The thing is I cannot access the token because httpOnly is set to true.

this is my code:

```
const task = {
    title: document.querySelector(classes.taskTitle).value,
    type: document.querySelector(classes.taskType).value,
    subject: document.querySelector(classes.taskSubject).value,
    date: document.querySelector(classes.taskDate).value,
    descriptions,
    timeFrame,
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/api/v1/tasks",// I cannot set authorization header to bearer token because document.cookie does not work
      data: task,
    });
    console.log(res.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data);
  }
```

Comment: Any reason you're deciding to use an `httpOnly` cookie that has to be translated into a header when returned back to the server? That sounds... impossible. Why not just use a `httpOnly` session cookie that gets passed back and forth?

Comment: basically, when sending the request to post a task, you need verification using jwt, and it gets the jwt from authorization using bearer token. The thing is, I can't access the cookie with httpOnly, and if I turn it off my website can be XSS attacked

Comment: Why not get the jwt back from a cookie that the front end sends? Is there any reason it absolutely needs to be in the Authorization header?